# How do I hide specific values of a button?

Tags: javascript, html, hidden

I have an app that generates Bootstrap buttons that hold these sensetive values: `data-value1="100" data-value2="I love you mamma"` as seen in my following code.

```
<button id="button-0" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="fetchValue(this)" data-value1="100" data-value2="I love you mamma">100</button>
```

I would like to keep these values hidden from unauthorized users, however, one is able to see these sensitive values when you click on it to **inspect it** via a browser like chrome. Is there a way I can hide these values while the button still holds these values?

Ideally, the following code is what I would like the user who clicks on the button to inspect it to see:

```
<button id="button-0" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="fetchValue(this)">100</button>
```

Comment: *"I would like to keep these values hidden from unauthorized users."* ... Wouldn't a user already be authorized to load this page in their browser? ...  What you could do is make it difficult to the average user to figure out what it says or means: obfuscation

Comment: I think the page is accessible even for the Unauthorized users, and that data basically hard-coded in the html, and it's the same page for both Authorized and Unauthorized, but just the data would be hidden in html for unauthorized ones.

Comment: @DhanaD. — Yeah … don't do that.

Comment: @GetSet You do actually have a point, these buttons WOULD be accessed by an authorized (logged in) user, your solution makes a lot of sense too.

Comment: @DhanaD. My thought is more towards the fact that an authorised user, might lose trust in the security of the application if they figure out just how easy it is to access their data personal data.

Comment: @GetSet is obfuscation possible on the client side via JavaScript?

Comment: It's possible. It will always be reversible however. There are some simple ways to "obfuscate" that the average user's eyes will interpret as programming junk. However someone on a mission will eventually figure out how to reverse it. The question you have to ask yourself, is how *sensitive* is the data you want to obfuscate? If it's something you never want reversed by any user, then don't store it to html nor client side scripts.

Comment: Some simple obfuscation techniques that are reversible include: (1) turning the data into a hex string, (2) ascii shifting the data, (3) xor'ing the data, or any combination of the foregoing. The reason it has to be "reversible" is your program must be able to get it back to what it really means.

Comment: One added note is, if the client-side has no need to do the "reversing", then you'd be better off using a "session store" server side, as opposed to tagging sensitive data along in the html. In this way, you never reveal the data from the get go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is running on your client side, so I don't think this is actually possible.

Anything that you need to be kept secret is going to need to be server side, ideally send it from your Controller to the client side.

Comment: But once sent from the server side to the client side, it's readable. I suppose the best solution would to never reveal any "sensitive" data to the client side unless the user is authorized and is privy to that data in the first place,